# GWT: Set text to be in the middle of the label (vertically)

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I am adding an image and a label to a HorizontalPanel.
The image is vertically aligned to the center, but the text in the label is always aligned to the top.

I am looking for a way to make the text appear in the middle of the label (and thus in the middle on the panel).

Comment: If you know the size of the text, you can set the top of the text to be 50% of the parent, then use a negative margin to offset it upwards half of the height of the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myPanel.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use alignment on horizontal panel like below code does.

```
panel.setCellHorizontalAlignment( image, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER );

panel.setCellHorizontalAlignment( label, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER );
```